# How to concatenate two images one on top of the other in Python?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, qr-code

I have 2 images that I want to merge together one on top of the other.

The first image is a user-uploaded restaurant Logo, the other is a QR code that I generate after the user uploads a restaurant Menu .pdf file (The QR code points to the URL of the menu file). How can I make it so that the Company logo is scaled correctly and above the newly made QR code?

Ideally, I would like to keep them separate and have a new function that renders them merged, with the logo above the QR code. This way the user can choose if they want the plain QR code or the one with the logo. Otherwise, if that's not possible, to be able to generate the QR code with the logo permanently embedded.

**Making the QR code in Models.py**

```
    class Menu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menuFile = models.FileField(upload_to='menus')
    qr_code = models.ImageField(upload_to='qr_codes', blank=True)
    uploadDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('restaurant', 'name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return(self.name)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qr = qrcode.QRCode(
            version=8,
            box_size = 10,
            border=5,
        )
        link = f'w w w.XX.com/{self.name}'
        qr.add_data(link)
        qr.make(fit=True)
        img = qr.make_image(fill='black', back_color='white')
        fname = f'{self.name}QRCode.png'
        buffer = BytesIO()
        img.save(buffer, 'PNG')
        self.qr_code.save(fname, File(buffer), save=False)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**The Restaurant model**

```
    class Restaurant(models.Model):
        account = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
        address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        restaurant_city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        zip_postal = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='logos', blank = True)
        date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet should do what you want to do in Pillow. The parts where you save it to Django, or where you keep the original, I leave up to you. The result is given below, as is the original (hypothetical) restaurant logo.

```
import qrcode
from PIL import Image

# Create qr code instance
qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1, error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H, box_size=4, border=.2)

# Add data
text = "www.this-is-some-url.com"
qr.add_data(text)
qr.make(fit=True)

# Create an image from the QR Code instance
qr_img = qr.make_image(fill_color='black', back_color='white')

# Load the logo
logo_img = Image.open('restaurant.jpeg')

# Scale the logo image. The width of the scaled logo shall be equal to the width of the QR code
qr_width, qr_height = qr_img.size
logo_current_width, logo_current_height = logo_img.size
scaling_factor = qr_width / logo_current_width
logo_new_height = int(scaling_factor * logo_current_height)
logo_new_size = (qr_width, logo_new_height)
logo_img = logo_img.resize(logo_new_size)

# Create an empty image to paste both images on
margin = 20
result = Image.new(mode='RGB', size=(qr_width, qr_height + margin + logo_new_height), color='white')
result.paste(logo_img, (0, 0))
result.paste(qr_img, (0, qr_height + margin))
result.save('restaurant_qr.jpg')
```

Result:

[image: restaurant_qr.jpg]

Original logo:

[image: restaurant.jpeg]